# Reserve/limit Passenger threads per Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, devops, system-administration

I have multiple Rails apps in the same server running with Nginx + Passenger. I use:

```
    passenger_max_pool_size 20;
    passenger_min_instances 20;
```

to fix the number of active passenger instance but, how I fix the number for each app independently? I would like to set for example:

- APP_A: 2 passenger instances
- APP_B: 18 passenger instances

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: It can only be done with [Passenger Enterprise](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise) using [MaxInstances](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengermaxinstances)

There is no clean solution for free version of Passenger